# Is there any easy way to use PowerCLI to sort ESX hosts based on their overall utilization?

Tags: sorting, powershell, vmware, powercli, utilization

I attempted to sort hosts using code that was similar to this (this may be slightly incorrect because I'm not currently at a box with PowerCLI installed):

```
$hosts = Get-VMHost
$SortedHosts = $hosts | Sort-Object CPUUsageMhz,MemoryUsageGB
```

The problem with this is that it is sorting it based on CPUUsageMhz first, then sorting it by MemoryUsageGB. I want to sort it so that the host with the overall lowest usage (Memory and CPU) is at the top/front of the list, and the most utilized host is at the bottom. An issue I ran into with my current sorting method is that a host with the lowest CPUUsageMhz had the highest MemoryUsageGB.

Answer (score 1):

Check out example 6 from the [Sort-Object help](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849912.aspx).

```
get-childitem *.txt | sort-object -property @{Expression={$_.LastWriteTime - $_.CreationTime}; Ascending=$false}
```

This illustrates how to design a custom sorting algorithm, with independent Ascending preference.

You will need to design the algorithm yourself, as there is no standard way to sort a combination of CPU and RAM use.  Depending on the complexity, you might need to resort to handling the sorting yourself, rather than using Sort-Object.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I'll start trying to figure out an algorithm to sort them better. I wasn't sure if there was an easier way to do it since it's using powercli; but this should work.